# Python - Requests Failed to establish a new connection BCB

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download this excel file https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/estatisticas/Documents/Tabelas_especiais/BalPagM.xlsx using the requests library.

When I open it in Google Chrome, it shows the following headers:

```
Request URL:
https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/estatisticas/Documents/Tabelas_especiais/BalPagM.xlsx
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

:Authority: www.bcb.gov.br
:Method: GET
:Path: /content/estatisticas/Documents/Tabelas_especiais/BalPagM.xlsx
:Scheme: https
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

When I run it from my Python code, I keep receiving "Failed to establish a new connection".

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/estatisticas/Documents/Tabelas_especiais/BalPagM.xlsx'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

To me, it seems that I am correctly setting all the headers. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just to set an answer here, the code was properly working. It was a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you're missing to write the fetched data into a file.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'host': 'www.bcb.gov.br'
}

url = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/estatisticas/Documents/Tabelas_especiais/BalPagM.xlsx'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('BalPagM.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Here, I am writing the response that is received from the request. I also updated the headers, since all of them weren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me without headers.

```py
import requests
from pathlib import Path


url = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/estatisticas/Documents/Tabelas_especiais/BalPagM.xlsx'
filename = Path(url).name

response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
if response.ok:
    Path(filename).write_bytes(response.content)
else:
    print(response.reason)
```